# Vue storefront: how to override function inside helper?

Tags: vue.js, vue-storefront

I need to modify 'preConfigureProduct' function under vuestorefront/core/modules/catalog/helpers/search.ts

https://github.com/vuestorefront/vue-storefront/blob/hotfix/v1.12.3/core/modules/catalog/helpers/search.ts#L51

I need to do the customisation based on my client requirement. Thus I need to override this function in my project.
But there is no document about how to override one function from helper. I am also new in vue storefront, so I dont fully understand module extending or mixins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more code and format it using the tools? Additionally and details about your issue like what you have tried to fix it so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out by myself, I will leave a short answer for who is stuck as well.
Additionally, I am not really sure it is a good practise, if you know a better way, leave it here please.

From what I understood is if you need to overwrite one function from helper, you also need to 'overwrite' the function which called your helper function.

In my case, I need to overwrite function preConfigureProduct , from module catalog helper.

The function called this preConfigureProduct is one asyc function configureProducts from module catalog-next, https://github.com/vuestorefront/vue-storefront/blob/hotfix/v1.12.3/core/modules/catalog-next/store/category/deprecatedActions.ts#L22.
(I know it is deprecatedActions. It is my next job to figure out how to switch to new ones)

Thus, I extended module catalog-next, and literally copy paste configureProducts(because I dont need to modify it), but import preConfigureProduct to my new file.

`import { preConfigureProduct } from './helpers/search'`

my new search.ts file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import config from 'config';

export const preConfigureProduct = ({ product, populateRequestCacheTags }) => {
    .....
  return product;
};
```

That is it !

Hopefully it helps others.
If there is any mistake, welcome to point it out.